# newobj instruction from CLR

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

**Andrew Troelsen** in his book [Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform, Fourth Edition](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-2008-NET-Platform-Fourth/dp/1590598849) says while explaining **newobj instruction from CLR** page no. 248, first para third bullet

> before returning the reference to the caller, advance the next object pointer to point to the next available slot on the managed heap

sounds like **advance the next object pointer** is winthin a `lock` block (or something similar) to make sure this pointer gets incremented correctly after every object creation on managed heap by all .net threads. Am i right or entirely wrong?

Comment: Yes, the function name is "EnterAllocLock".  You can see a possible implementation of it in the SSCLI20 version of the CLR, clr/src/vm/gcsmp.cpp source code file.  It has a rather unusual optimization that I don't want to try to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is an implementation detail. There are many ways to implement this, and a CLR implementation is free to choose whichever it likes.

A few possible implementations:

1. Use locking as you suggest
2. Use " lockless" methods like `Interlocked.Exchange`
3. Allocate from different areas in each thread. For example by having a separate Gen0 heap per thread.

Comment: `implementation detail`, sounds like only **CLR Team** can post exact answer.

Comment: No, the point is that it doesn't matter and you can't assume any particular implementation. There is no one "CLR Team". Microsoft has a team that works on their CLR, but they're not the only game in town.

Comment: http://www.intertech.com/Instructors/Default.aspx?InstructorID=1 Andrew is Microsoft MVP, that means he might have read-only access to the exact source code, http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2003/oct03/10-22MVPSLP2003PR.mspx I guess in this paragraph he unintentionally wrote too much about the implementation details which you as a developer should never care about. Like @CodyGray pointed out, there are indeed other CLR implementations such as Mono, so you should not assume all such clones use the same approach.